# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter Validation failed: Email can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, twitter, devise, omniauth

Whilst trying to implement Omniauth-twitter into my Rails app I've hit the error stated above. 
The error centres on a statement in my controller and I understand it relates to the fact twitter does not provide an email on callback. I'm using devise for authentication. I also intend to install Facebook omniauth but want to get Twitter working first.
What code block can I implement to skip this validation for Twitter? Does it go in my controller or user model?

Here's my code as it stands -

OmniauthCallbacksController -

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def twitter

     @details = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

    @provider = @details["provider"]
    @provider_id = @details["uid"]

    @user = User.where(provider: @provider, provider_id: @provider_id).first

    if @user.present?
        #sign them in
    else
        # make a new user
        @user = User.new
        @user.provider = @provider
        @user.provider_id = @provider_id

        # because of has_secure_password - will this work?
        @user.password = "AAAAAA!!"
        @user.password_confirmation = "AAAAAA!!"

        # let's save the key and secret
        @user.key = @details["credentials"]["token"]
        @user.secret = @details["credentials"]["secret"]

        # lets fill in their details
        @user.name = @details["info"]["name"]
        @user.email = @details["info"]["email"]

        @user.save!
    end


        session[:uid] = @user.id 
        flash[:success] = "You've logged in"
        redirect_to root_path

end

def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
end






end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  #get "/auth/:provider/callback" => "social_logins#create"


  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks:     "omniauth_callbacks", registrations: 'registrations' }  



  resources :users
  resources :events do

    resources :bookings
  end
  # get 'welcome/index'


  authenticated :user do
    root 'events#index', as: "authenticated_root"
  end


    root 'welcome#index'




end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,     omniauth_providers: [:twitter]

         has_many :events
         has_many :bookings
         has_many :authentications




end
```

Comment: Are you sure `@details["info"]["email"]` this is not nil or something?

Comment: No. It needs to fall outside this validation so the callback works.

Comment: `:validatable` is the thing which validates the presence of `email`. So you could may be remove `:validatable` and your own validations. See here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb

Comment: I'm not keen on removing validations just for this, that's why I'd rather place some code to avoid it happening with twitter log in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with this line of code in the OmniauthCallbackController

```
  # lets fill in their details
        @user.name = @details["info"]["name"]
        if @provider == "twitter"? @user.save!(:validate => false) : @user.save!
        # the above if statement allows for twitter to skip validation which requires an email
        @user.email = @details["info"]["email"]
        end

        @user.save!
```